# only IExplorer 11 raising Angular.js exception

Tags: angularjs, exception, internet-explorer-11

I'm debugging a site/app that uses angular v1.2.26, build by people who know Angular but are myself a newbee with Angular.

When I open it in IExplorer 11/win7 I recieve this error sporadically:

```
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module main due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'main' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/nomod?p0=main
   at Anonymous function ...........
```

(If I open in Chrome / Firefox / Opera this is NOT an issue - I have other issues;-) but not this)

I have found all sort of explanations for this, but none of them specific for iExplorer (I mean: none of them happens ONLY in Internet explorer - they all seems to happens in every browser, and that is not my case)

The other thing that drives my crazy is that the exceptions happens maybe 3/4 of the times. Some times it loads just fine...

So, the question is: has somebody a clue of what could be happening just in iExplorer?

I'll provide more info if needed...

/thanks
/j

Comment: What does the code look like that defines the module `main`?

Comment: Perhaps `main` is in a separate *.js file, and your browser isn't loading them in the correct order? Without seeing some code we can only guess.

Comment: Could IE be caching an older version of some file?

Comment: @link64 I'm opening in private mode, so it shouldn't be caching.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Microsoft JScript runtime error: \[$injector:modulerr\] in AngularJS v1.3.0-beta.11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114556/microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-injectormodulerr-in-angularjs-v1-3-0-beta-1)